# How to implement this modified version of an interpolation algorithm on an image (Bayer filtering)?

Tags: python, matlab, image-processing, scipy, scikit-image

I'm trying to implement a modified version of the interpolation algorithm, where all values from valid neighbors are averaged. Example, in the Green channel: [see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w9fIv.jpg)

But I think I'm having issues when filling in the missing values.

[Here is my output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qeeVy.png)

[This is the output I'm expecting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZAqqE.png)

I seem to be getting these gridlines in the output which are - I guess, missing pixels. I'm not sure where I am making this error so any help would be appreciated!

Here is my code:

```
    # read image
    img = io.imread(filename_Grayimage, as_gray =True)
    h,w = img.shape

    # set figure size of the plot 
    plt.figure(figsize=(10,8))

    # our final image will be a 3 dimensional image with 3 channels
    rgb = np.zeros((h,w,3),np.uint8)

    # reconstruction of the green channel IG
    IG = np.copy(img) # copy the image into each channel
    for row in range(0,h,4): # loop step is 4 since our mask size is 4.
        for col in range(0,w,4): # loop step is 4 since our mask size is 4.
            # Shaded Image Locations
            gA = int(img[row, col])
            gC = int(img[row, col+2])
            gF = int(img[row+1, col+1])
            gH = int(img[row+1, col+3])
            gI = int(img[row+2, col])
            gK = int(img[row+2, col+2])
            gN = int(img[row+3, col+1])
            gP = int(img[row+3, col+3])
    
            # Equations for valid neighbours
            # B = (A+C+F)/3
            # D = (C+H)/2
            # E = (A+F+I)/3
            # G = (F+C+H+K)/4
            # J = (F+I+K+N)/4
            # L = (H+K+P)/3
            # M = (I+N)/2
            # O = (N+K+P)/2

            # TODO: compute pixel value for each location where mask is unshaded (0) 
            # interpolate each pixel using its every valid (shaded) neighbors
            IG[row, col+1] = (gA+gC+gF)/3  # B
            IG[row, col+3] = (gC+gH)/2 # D
            IG[row+1, col+1] = (gA+gF+gI)/3 # E
            IG[row+1, col+2] = (gF+gC+gH+gK)/4 # G
            IG[row+2, col+2] = (gF+gI+gK+gN)/4 # J 
            IG[row+2, col+3] = (gH+gK+gP)/3 # L
            IG[row+3, col] = (gI+gN)/2 # M
            IG[row+3, col+2] = (gN+gK+gP)/2 # O

    # [x] TODO: show green (IR) in first subplot (221) and add title - refer to rgb one for hint on plotting
    plt.subplot(221)
    plt.imshow(IG, cmap='gray')
    plt.title('IG')
```

Comment: Well... Aren't you convinced yet that my answer is absolutely correct ? ✔✔✔

Answer (score 1):

This looks like an exercise so I'm not going to just tell you the errors. Hopefully this helps you to track them down yourself.

---

The basic algorithm is correct*, but there are a two problems with the implementation. Have a close look at your equations and the interpolation code again. You are guessing that there might be missing pixels, so check that a) the correct pixels are replaced and b) the replaced pixels have the correct values.

I'm going to point you to some ways you can use to hunt down such bugs.

**Use simple images with exactly known output for testing.**
I'm talking about e.g. all black, all white and all grey images. Here the output for these images should be the same as the input. Is this the case? If not, is there a recognisable pattern that could narrow down the problem?

**Replace the algorithm with something simpler.**
You should be able to find the other problem if you replace the interpolation with setting all of the interpolated pixels to a fixed value (e.g. 0).
It's even more obvious if you use an input image with a single intensity value (e.g. 255) but you'll see it with your input image, too.
This bug is somewhat hidden by the copying of the input image into the output image, but you would notice with an actual GBRG or GRBG image as input.

---

* In that it will do an interpolation, not in that it is the best way to do it. See [Rotem's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75597894/21275537) for a better way.

Comment: It is probably an exercise, but it might as well be a simplified demosaicing algorithm (fast demosaicing algorithm). Beside, there is still enough work for handling the red and the blue pixels (we are only answering about the green pixels, which is reasonable help for an exercise). Using an input image with a single intensity is a good idea - I acutely used it when debugging my answer.

Comment: @Rotem That's probably true, but the simple, direct answer of pointing out the wrong lines (assuming that the algorithm is as intended) is not helpful to anyone else, and barely even helpful to the OP. Would you suggest to edit in that information (in addition, of course, not as a replacement)?

Comment: Simply giving the correct code is not helpful. As I see it, a "teaching answer" may be very helpful for the OP assuming they really want to learn.

Comment: @Rotem it is an exercise and a "teaching answer" would be the best! I really am trying to figure out where I'm going wrong and not just copy down code that works! I will look over your reply and try to apply it to what I have + other channels thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The chart is "super confusing", because it shows the bounties of the image.
All the red/blue pixels that are not in the edges has 4 valid green neighbors.
There should be no average of 3 neighbors at all (except for the margins).

---

Take a look at `G` (assume red pixel):
`G` = (`C` + `F` + `H` + `K`) / 4

[image]

---

Take a look at `J` (assume blue pixel):

`J` = (`I` + `F` + `K` + `N`) / 4

[image]

---

Except for the margins we may apply the following rule:

- For each even rows (0, 2, 4...) we are replacing pixels in even columns (0, 2, 4...) with average of 4 neighbors.
- For each odd rows (1, 3, 5...) we are replacing pixels in odd columns (1, 3, 5...) with average of 4 neighbors.

---

Handling the margins:
For making simpler we may pad the image with one row at the top, one row at the bottom, one column to the left and one column to the right.
In the padded image, each red/blue pixel has 4 "valid" green neighbors.

For the padding we are taking the second neighbor row/column (not the first) for keeping the correct Bayer alignment.

---

You didn't post an input image...
I created the following image with GRBG Bayer alignment for testing:
[image]

---

Code sample:

```python
import imageio as io
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Bayer pattern of peppers_bayer.png is GRBG
filename_Grayimage = 'peppers_bayer_grbg.png'

# read image
img = io.imread(filename_Grayimage, as_gray=True)
img = img.astype(np.uint8)  # imageio reads the data float type - convert the type to uint8 (working with integer pixels).
h, w = img.shape

# set figure size of the plot 
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 8))

# our final image will be a 3 dimensional image with 3 channels
#rgb = np.zeros((h, w, 3), np.uint8)

# Add padding of 1 row at the top, one row at the bottom, one column at the left and on at the right.
img = np.pad(img, ((1, 1), (1, 1)))
img[:, 0] = img[:, 2]  # Copy the second column (not the first) for keeping the Bayer pattern correct.
img[:, -1] = img[:, -3]
img[0, :] = img[2, :]
img[-1, :] = img[-3, :]

# reconstruction of the green channel IG
IG = np.copy(img) # copy the image into each channel

# Size after padding is w+2 by h+2
w += 2
h += 2

for row in range(1, h-1, 2): # loop steps of 2 - each iteration applies one even and one odd row.
    # Padding - lower case.
    # Original pixels - upper case
    #
    # -------------- padding
    # |        |
    # V        V
    # gbgbgbgbgg <-- padding
    # rGRGRGRGRr
    # gBGBGBGBGg
    # rGRGRGRGRr
    # gBGBGBGBGg
    # rgrgrgrgrr <-- padding

    # Odd row:
    # Note: first row is odd, because row starts from 1
    for col in range(2, w-1, 2):  # Odd row: Start from col=2, because pixel in col=1 is green
        #  G 
        # G*G
        #  G
        C = int(img[row-1, col])
        E = int(img[row, col-1])
        F = int(img[row, col+1])
        H = int(img[row+1, col])
        IG[row, col] = np.round((C + E + F + H) / 4)  # Each "filled pixel" is an average of 4 neighbors

    # Even row:
    row1 = row + 1  # One row below <row>
    for col in range(1, w-2, 2):  # Even Row: start from col=1, because pixel in col=1 is blue
        #  G 
        # G*G
        #  G
        F = int(img[row1-1, col])
        I = int(img[row1, col-1])
        K = int(img[row1, col+1])
        N = int(img[row1+1, col])
        IG[row1, col] = np.round((F + I + K + N) / 4)    # Each "filled pixel" is an average of 4 neighbors

# Remove the padding:
IG = IG[2:-1, 2:-1]

# [x] TODO: show green (IR) in first subplot (221) and add title - refer to rgb one for hint on plotting
plt.subplot(221)
plt.imshow(IG, cmap='gray')
plt.title('IG')
plt.show()
```

---

Output:
[image]